# Is there a way to combine two conditions in a CASE WHEN SQL Statement?

Tags: sql, null, conditional-statements, case-when, multiple-conditions

I'm creating a yes/no flag for SQL data and I have something similar to:

'''
CASE WHEN col_name IS NULL OR col_name = 0 THEN "N"
ELSE "Y"
END AS col_name_flag
'''

Is there any way to be more concise so I don't have to have the column name written out twice? Many of the column names are very long so I was wondering if there would be a way to make it more visually pleasing.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the simplest method is to reverse the comparison:

```
(CASE WHEN col_name <> 0 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END) AS col_name_flag
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use:

```
CASE IsNull(col_name,0) =0 THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END as col_name_flag
```

But I would go with Gordon's answer for performance...